# Composing probability distribution functions

Tags: distributions

Suppose I have a random variable $S$, that is drawn from a distribution $F_a$ with parameter equal to a random variable $a$.  Suppose the parameters $a$ are drawn from a separate distribution $G$, with constant known parameters.  What can I say about the distribution of $S$?

To clarify, we would generate the dataset as follows.  For each datapoint:

1. Draw $a$ randomly from the distribution $G$.
2. Given our value of $a$, draw $S$ randomly from the distribution $F_a$.

How might I go about finding the CDF of $S$, if I had nice expressions for $F_a$ (in terms of $a$) and $G$?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Bayesian Predictive Distributions](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72697/understanding-bayesian-predictive-distributions)

Comment: This is called a [*mixture* distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution). In the cases where $a$ takes uncountably many values it may also be called a compound distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Your objective can be accomplished with a bit of calculus and algebra.  First suppose that you have the probability density/mass function for $S$, call it $f(s)$.  Given the parameter $a$ then let's write the conditional density of $S$ as
$$
f(s|a).
$$

Suppose you also have the density of $a$, which we'll write as $g(a)$.  Then the joint density of $(s,a)$ is just the product $f(s|a)g(a)$.  Thus the **marginal** density of $s$ will be
$$
f(s) = \int f(s|a) g(a) da
$$
(If $a$ is discrete, then replace the integration with a summation over the support of $a$.) This process of multiplying together conditional with marginal and integrating is an extremely common operation in Bayesian statistics, hence the link to the other question.  The object you are in interested in, in Bayesian statistics, could be called a *prior predictive distribution*.

If instead you have joint distribution functions, then it still holds that the joint distribution function $F(a, s) = F(s|a) F(a).$  Now you don't need to any integration.  Instead, the marginal **distribution** function for $s$ is just
$$
F(\infty, s)
$$
or whatever the maximum value that $A$ may obtain is.