# Posterior predictive distribution simulation: why not average over parameter values?

Tags: bayesian, predictive-models

I'm very unfamiliar with Bayesian statistics, so forgive me if this question is obvious. The idea of a posterior predictive distribution seems to be incorporate uncertainty about the parameter $\theta$ (or, I guess, its estimate if you look at it in the classical way) when simulating and/or predicting the distribution of a new observation, and is based on the formula
$$
p(y_+ \mid y_1, \dots, y_n) = \int p(y_+ \mid \theta) p(\theta \mid y_1, \dots, y_n) \, d\theta \,.
$$
However, the sources I've found, (including [answers on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/335496/30492)) suggest that one should simulate realisations of $Y_+$ by sampling $\theta^{(i)}$ from $\Theta \mid Y_1= y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n$ and $y_+^{(i)}$ from $Y_+ \mid \Theta = \theta$. Why is it not necessary to average over $\theta$ here? Intuitively, the correct procedure seems to me rather to be:

1. Draw $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_M$ from $\Theta \mid Y_1= y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n$
2. For each $\theta_i$, draw $y_+^{(1, \theta_i)}, \dots, y_+^{(N, \theta_i)}$ from $Y_+ \mid \Theta = \theta$
3. $y_+^{(j)} := \frac{1}{M}\sum_{i = 1}^M y_+^{(j, \theta_i)}$ for $i = 1, \dots, N$ is a sample from $Y_+ \mid Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n$

What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: "sampling $\theta^{(i)}$ from $\Theta \mid Y_1= y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n$" has the effect of averaging over $\theta$ with its posterior distribution, at least in a simulation sense of averaging.  The two procedures you put forward have the same expectations but if your alternative procedure in effect has $NM$ simulations, then the original procedure would enable a wider number of possible values of $\theta$ to be found.

Comment: @Henry that doesn't make sense to me. Sampling $x^{(i)}$ form a standard normal distribution doesn't have the effect of averaging over it, you still need to compute the arithmetic average. Why is this different?

Comment: Suppose you plotted your $(\theta_i, y_+^{(j, \theta_i)})$ points: you would have $NM$ simulated points made up of $M$ lines - one for each $\theta_i$ - with $N$ points on each line.  Having $NM$ independent points $(\theta_k, y_+^{(k, \theta_k)})$ might give a better view of the overall predictive distribution

Comment: @Henry ok, that makes a little more sense already. Is there a way to make this mathematically rigorous? Do you know of a source giving a formal proof of the claim that this procedure approximates the distribution $Y_+ \mid Y_1 = y_1, \dots, Y_n = y_n$?